# Why does division near to zero have different behaviors in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, division

This is not actually a problem, it is more something curious about floating-point arithmetic on Python implementation.

Could someone explain the following behavior?

```
>>> 1/1e-308
1e+308
>>> 1/1e-309
inf
>>> 1/1e-323
inf
>>> 1/1e-324
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

It seems that 1 divided by a number near to zero is `inf` and if it is nearer to a `ZeroDivisionError` is thrown. It seems an odd behavior.

The same output for python 2.x/3.x.

---

**EDIT**: my main question here is why we get `inf` for some range and not `ZeroDivisionError` assuming that python seems to consider as zero 1e-309

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to the IEEE754 floating-point format itself, not so much Python's implementation of it.

Generally speaking, floats can represent smaller negative exponents than large positive ones, because of [denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number). This is where the mantissa part of the float is no longer implicitly assumed to begin with a 1, but rather describes the entire mantissa, and begins with zeroes. In case you don't know what that is, I'd suggest you read up about how floats are represented, perhaps starting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Because of this, when you invert a denormal number, you may end up with a positive exponent too large to represent. The computer then gives you `inf` in its place. The `1e-308` in your example is actually also denormal, but still not small to overflow when inverted (because among normal numbers, the standard actually allows for slightly larger positive than negative exponents).

In case of `1e-324`, that number is simply too small to be represented even as a denormal, so that float literal is effectively equal to zero. That's why you get division by zero. The smallest representable 64-bit float is (slightly below) `5e-324`.

Comment: This is completely related to Python's (non-)implementation of IEEE 754. A sane programming language would let the division happen (the processor implements it correctly, unlike the Python designers) and produce the appropriate result. Instead, Python explicitly tests whether the divisor is zero and behaves differently in this case. This takes extra cycles, doesn't prevent overflow from happening, and mean Python is not IEEE 754 compliant (since in IEEE 754 1.0 / 0.0 produces +inf).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Technically, that is not entirely true, as you'd get an exception with IEEE754 arithmetic *if you have traps enabled*. Since that is far from default behavior, though, your point is valid, conceded and noteworthy. However, the difference between the two behaviors are explained by the inversion of denormals allowing overflow to be produced, so I don't think the answer needs to be reformulated.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum value that can be used as float numer in Python is :

`2.2250738585072014e-308`

Python uses double-precision floats, which can hold values from about 10 to the -308 to 10 to the 308 power.

[Wikipedia - double precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Actually, you can probably get numbers smaller than 1e-308 via [denormals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number),But there is a significant performance hit to this. I found that Python is able to handle `1e-324` but underflows on `1e-325` and returns `0.0` as the value.

Comment: Thank you, I see. However, I don't understand yet why we get `inf` for a little range and not `ZerroDivisionError` as python should return. Could it be something intentional in the language design?

Comment: @emartinelli As I tested `1e-323` is not equal by zero but `1e-324` is equal to zero in Python shell thats why divisionByZero raised. and as I mentiond minimum value in python as float is `2.22e-308` and smaller than this value I think Python dosen't do any mathematical computation with them and just a `try catch` for doesnt raise `divideByZero` error

Comment: "*But there is a significant performance hit to this*" -- Just for the record, this is not necessarily true. I believe most of the big architectures from Intel and AMD handle denormals, infinities and NaNs with no extra penalty. Also, it should perhaps also be said that the penalty is going to be rather miniscule compared to the penalty of running interpreted Python code anyway. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the things have already been explained by Dolda2000 in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35400208/3375713). Yet it might be helpful to *see* this.

```
>>> 1e-308
1e-308
>>> 1e-309
1e-309
>>> 1e-323
1e-323
>>> 1e-324
0.0
```

As you can see `1e-324` is equal to `0.0` in python implementation. As Dolda2000 put it very nicely: *that number is simply too small to be represented even as a denormal, so that float literal is effectively equal to zero*